# Access SDK-internal localisations like "Done", "Search" etc

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When I build a UI in  iOS I want to make it as familiar as possible. So imagine I make a non-standard button which should still have the caption "Done" (In multiple languages).

I could now tediously try to figure out what the "Done button" is called in all those languages by changing the device language.

I am wondering if there is a way to access such "internal translations" in my code.